# Nested Hashmaps best practices?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, hashmap

I find myself using nested Dictionaries and LinkedHashMaps fairly often. It has me thinking, is this good practice or should I be using some other data structure. Often times my maps are 3D in nature.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>> mapOfOIDS = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>>
```

It can often be messy to work with at times and was wondering if there was a better approach? For this instance I want to model a number of unique hostname, who have a list of unique port number, who have a list of unique OIDS.

Comment: It depends on how the data is looked up. If you need to do lookups based on intermediate information, nested maps may be appropriate. If you're only doing lookups based on the hostname though, a single map of string->class (where `class` is a POD class holding ports and OIDS, and such) may be easier to work with.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that per se, but don't expose the structure to calling code. Provide the required query- and update functions and make sure that all the details are encapsulated in a class acting as a repository for this data, so that any "messy-ness" is limited to the smallest possible scope. If your data is large, it may be worth looking into in-memory DBs and their query languages instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually combine the three `String` keys into one using some kind of delimiter.
Let the current data as per your implementation be
`{ "abc" :{ "qwe" : {"qaz" : "MYDATA"}}}`
Here you could combine the three keys into one as `abc~qwe~qaz`. So the resultant map would be `{"abc~qwe~qaz" : "MYDATA"}`